# Can't seem to configure my phone to download to SD card by default

Tags: google-play-store, internal-storage, adb, external-sd, motorola-razr-i

Well, I have a *Motorola Razr I* and, as expected, my internal storage was pretty limited (only 5 gbs). Of course, I already had a SD card which I inserted into my phone to expand it's memory to 25 gbs (more or less), but ran into a couple of problems.
First of those problems was that I had to specify to my Razr that, from now on, my default install and download location would be the aforementioned SD card and, in order to do that, I had to run the following command line: `... set-install-location 2`.
After a couple of failed attempts, I managed to make it work. I wrote such line in the command prompt and managed to verify that, indeed, the default install location was "2".  Unfortunately, when I tried downloading an app off Google Play, I still got the `Not enough memory available` message. The worst part is that I went through the process over and over again and could not find where my mistake was.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Android 4.4, write permissions to sd card for apps have been disabled. If you're rooted, you can try SD Fix to permanently fix permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're rooted and have a custom ROM, you can try [this](http://droidrazrmyway.blogspot.com/p/using-motorola-droid-razrs-external.html).
Basically mounts your external SD card as the internal SD card, and the internal as the external.

Comment: I'm not rooted, and I do not have a custom ROM. Is there any other way around?

Comment: doesn't seem to be... Not that I could find. Seems a common problem with RAZR's though